# how to retrieve a specific td from a table inside an IFrame using jquery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to retrieve a td using the "title" attribute value but cant seem to get it to work using the code example below:

```
var iframe = $("#iframe1");
var tr = iframe.contents().find("td[title='2015-02-06']").text();
alert(tr);
```

Below is the HTML source I'm testing the code against. Preferably I would like the code to use the table id as well in the selector as I have other tables in the iframe.
    Any ideas please ?

```
 <iframe id=iframe1>
<TABLE id=table1>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD title=2015-02-01>1</TD>
<TD title=2015-02-02>2</TD>
<TD title=2015-02-03>3</TD>
<TD title=2015-02-04>4</TD>
<TD title=2015-02-05>5</TD>
<TD title=2015-02-06>6</TD>
<TD title=2015-02-07>7</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD title=2015-02-08>8</TD>
<TD title=2015-02-09>9</TD>
<TD title=2015-02-10>10</TD>
<TD title=2015-02-11>11</TD>
<TD title=2015-02-12>12</TD>
<TD title=2015-02-13>13</TD>
<TD title=2015-02-14>14</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD title=2015-02-15>15</TD>
<TD title=2015-02-16>16</TD>
<TD title=2015-02-17>17</TD>
<TD title=2015-02-18>18</TD>
<TD title=2015-02-19>19</TD>
<TD title=2015-02-20>20</TD>
<TD title=2015-02-21>21</TD>
</TR>

    </TBODY>
     </TABLE>
    </iframe>
```

Comment: It should work; you just have to make sure that `iframe` contents are already loaded when you're making this particular query.

Comment: tested the code in: [http://jsfiddle.net] and the alert message is blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**iframe**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) is supposed to embed `documents` but not `plain` html. Put the html in some file suppose test.html and import that document in the iframe then you selector will bring the contents.

The IFRAME element allows authors to insert a frame within a block of text. Inserting an inline frame within a section of text is much like inserting an object via the OBJECT element: they both allow you to insert an HTML document in the middle of another, they may both be aligned with surrounding text, etc, You can read more over [**w3.org**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html)

*You can check the working of your selector* **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/9cFpe/)**

Comment: thanks Adil, as already pointed out by Blender as well. What i would like to know is if this selector is valid within an iframe as Blender did make a comment on the title attribute.....

Comment: Thanks Adil, that works, now to use this within a (real) iframe , how would the code look like using the table id as well ?

Comment: I guess my question is would this $("#iFrameId").contents().find("#tableId").find("td[title='2015-02-06']").text()) work ?

Comment: the following worked ! s i guess this is just more of a syntax issue on the frame handle using Jquery syntax: $(window.frames["frame1"].document.getElementById(\"table1\")).find(\"td[title='2015-02-14']\")

Answer (score 1):

`<iframe>` elements shouldn't have anything [inside of them](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-iframe-element.html):

> An iframe element never has fallback content, as it will always create
>   a nested browsing context, regardless of whether the specified initial
>   contents are successfully used.
>
> **Descendants of iframe elements represent nothing.** (In legacy user
>   agents that do not support iframe elements, the contents would be
>   parsed as markup that could act as fallback content.)

I'm not sure why you're using an iframe in the first place. This looks like a job for a `<div>` tag, but if you absolutely need the contents in an iframe, put that HTML into a new file and just change the `src` attribute of the iframe to point to it.

Also, the `title` attribute doesn't belong in an iframe element. Use a `data-` attribute (`data-date` maybe?) or an `id`.

Comment: thanks Blender for clarifying the <iframe> tag.  The project uses the iframe to open up several windows so not somthing i can easily change for now. Re the title are u saying this wont work using the title attribute as this is my only option for now

Comment: @stack: If you can, replace `title` with `data-date` in your code. Read some tutorials on how to use `<iframe>` elements.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you replace "title" in the TD with "id" attribute and directly use it.

HTML:

```
<TD id="2015-02-06">6</TD>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#2015-02-06").text();
```

Comment: the id attribute is already been used for something else, I cleaned it out before pasting it here to make it easy to read as its assgined to a rather long string.... value